# Error when using node.js method path.extname()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using Electron. I have written a program that recursively reads the files of a directory. Now I want that files with a certain extname (file extension) are not shown. In order to do that I need the node.js method path.extname(path) which return the extname.
My problem is that the path.extname() method does not work at that place in the code I need it.
Outside of my function scan_directory_to_html() it works and returns .jpg but inside of the function I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: path.extname is not a function`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

//This works:
console.log(path.extname(`${__dirname}/../../project_files/sprites/Appenzell.jpg`));

function scan_directory_to_html(directory){
  var zw_directory_array = fs.readdirSync(directory);
  var zw_to_html = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < zw_directory_array.length; i++){
      var path = directory + zw_directory_array[i];

      //This produces the error message
      console.log(path.extname(`${__dirname}/../../project_files/sprites/Appenzell.jpg`));

      if(fs.lstatSync(path).isFile()){
        zw_to_html += "<a href='#' onClick='create_sprite_window(`"+ path +"`)'><li><img src='" + path + "'/>" + zw_directory_array[i] + "</li></a>";
      }else if(fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()){

        zw_to_html += "<li class='li_directory'>" + zw_directory_array[i] + "</li>";
        zw_to_html += "<ul>";
        zw_to_html += scan_directory_to_html(path + "/");
        zw_to_html += "</ul>";
      }else{
        console.log("Error in function scan_directory_to_html(): Path is neither directory nor file.");
      }
    }
  return zw_to_html;
}

document.getElementById('sidebar_left_sprites').innerHTML = scan_directory_to_html(`${__dirname}/../../project_files/sprites/`);
```

I have also tried to put `const path = require('path');` inside the function as well but it then says that the Identifier 'path' has already been declared.
How can I use the path.extname() method inside of the function?

Comment: You are overwriting the path module when you do `var path = directory + zw_directory_array[i];`, call it something other than `path`

Comment: @dtkaias Thanks for your response. I did not think that through when I made that path variable. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

The `path` is conflicted in your code. Use another name in below.

```
var filepath = directory + zw_directory_array[i];
```

instead

```
var path = directory + zw_directory_array[i];
```